# Intento pasar un arreglo a una vista pero me da error

Tags: laravel, array, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Las siguientes son las líneas de código que uso, intento pasar el arreglo $items a la vista work_flow, he usado muchas formas pero la vista siguie sin aceptar la estructura del array, entiendo que usa estructas de tipo colecction pero no sé como carmbiar el array hacia esa estructura de manera que sea asimilable por la vista:

```
Route::get('demo', function() {
    $items = [
        'document_type'     => [
        '10' => 'Seller',
        '20' => 'Agent',
    ]
];

//return view('models.activity.work_flow', ['items'=>$items]);
//return view('models.activity.work_flow')->with(['items'=>$items]);
//return view('models.activity.work_flow')->with($items);
return view('models.activity.work_flow', compact('items'));

});
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás mandando a la vista un array que a su vez tiene por dentro una clave con un array asociativo como valor asignado.

Dicho lo anterior, no requieres estrictamente convertirlo a una instancia de la clase `Collection`, con iterarlo de esta forma queda resuelto:

```
@foreach($data["document_type"] as $dato)
    {{ $dato }}
@endforeach
```

Como notas lo único que hacemos es que cuando comenzamos la iteración indicamos la clave a la cual inicialmente debe acceder, para a partir de ahi obtener los valores deseados.

Ahora si quieres que sea una instancia de *collection*, basta con que lleves a cabo estos pasos:

1. Importa por su namespace a dicha clase:

   ```
   use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
   ```
2. Te apoyas del helper `collect` para que el array pasado sea una instancia de la clase ya mencionada:

   ```
    $data = collect($items = [
            'document_type'     => [
            '10' => 'Seller',
            '20' => 'Agent',
        ]
    ]);

    dd($data);
   ```

Que te da una salida como esta:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#280 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    "document_type" => array:2 [▼
      10 => "Seller"
      20 => "Agent"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Seguirás logrando iterarlos de manera normal, solo que [ahora podrás acceder a los métodos que dicha clase ofrece](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods)

Comment: Te agradezco por tu apoyo, me ayudó tu respuesta y funcionó correctamente, ya puedo pasar arreglos a las vistas convirtiéndolos en colecciones, ahora para aplicarlo a mi proyecto necesito que el arreglo contenga varios registros como si fuera un modelo que pasaría como variable a la vista donde con un @foreach pueda hacer referencia a sus datos de ésta forma <div>{{ $item->nombre }}</div>

Comment: @CarlosPleitez eso ya sería una pregunta distinta, conviene que si quieres ayuda al respecto trates algo y posterior publiques si gustas una duda nueva

Comment: Comprendo gracias por la orientación así lo haré